# Try to build adosbox with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime-error, compiler-warnings, dosbox

This is what I done

- svn checkout source trunk (adosbox source code from google code)
- download Eclipse
- build adosbox with Eclipse
- build and install successfully on emulator/mobile.

BUT when I execute it Shows error message unfortunately adosbox has stopped.

also 0 errors but contains 2 warning , some yellow exclamation sign in MainActivity.java

Please help!!!!!!!!!!

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      if (requestCode == SELECT_CONFIG) {
          Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

shows warning : The value of the local variable selectedImageUri is not used    MainActivity.java   /adosbox/src/org/hystudio/android/dosbox    line 215    Java Problem

Comment: Is this android? Set the android tag if it is.

Comment: i don't understand what you trying to convey!!!!!!!

Comment: If you are doing this for Android then it is important that you set one of the tags on the question to be `android`, otherwise it is unlikely that anyone who can answer the question will see it.